# Function for slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Basically i want to do small slider for website which will load after every slide load but that's not my problem. Problem is the function. Function need to get numbers of elements (photos) in gallery(div) and run that many time as number of photos.
So for example if i have on slide 3 photos, it will run 3 times, if 4 them 4 times.

This is my jquery code:

```
function slider() {
    var div = 0;
    var photos = $(‘.photo_gallery’).length;
    /*
        $('.portfolio_gallery > div').eq(div - 1).hide(1500);
        $('.gallery_pages > img').eq(div - 1).attr("src", "../images/rotator.png");
        $('.portfolio_gallery > div').eq(div).show(1500);
        $('.gallery_pages > img').eq(div).attr("src", "../images/rotator.gif");
        div + 1;
    */
    if (div < photos) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.portfolio_gallery > div').eq(div).show(1500);
            $('.gallery_pages > img').eq(div).attr("src", "../images/rotator.gif");
        }, 7000)
    }
}
```

Don't bother with commented section but it might be helpful if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-invent the slider. You have JQuery, use [jCarousel](https://plugins.jquery.com/jcarousel/).